# Laravel Return Migration and Eloquent Response

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, migration

Is there any way to get the response or message from the migration and eloquent? Regardless of success or failure.

Migration:

```
$response = Artisan::call('make:model', [
    'name' => 'MyModel'
    '-m' => true
]);
//I need the response for my next step
```

Eloquent:

```
$response = MyModel::create($myValues);
//I need the response for my next step
```

Comment: $response = MyModel::create($myValues); for this you will get created object as response.

Comment: @VishalTarkar is there a way to know if something wrong while creating so that we can know when to rollback to the previous action.

Comment: It might be worth to check what is passed to the [output buffer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b69db31d47342f41878c20cbdce35edc8ea56147/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php#L259)

Comment: Sure! There is. You can add this particular code in Try Catch. & Use DB transaction to rollback too.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
$myModel = new myModel();
$myModel->value = 'value';
$myModel->save(); // you can use create or other function here
```

Now your result is in `$myModel`. It's not related to migration.

Comment: what if failed? I wanna know the reason for the failure while saving.

Comment: what is your model and table?